# Which domain $\Sigma$ is f analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

define $f(z) = \dfrac{\log(z)}{z}$.

suppose that $log(z)$ is the principal branch i.e defined only on $(-\pi,\pi]$. Is the domain at which f(z) analytic $\Sigma = C - ((-\infty,0])$?

Answer (score 1):

A holomorphic function is analytic on any domain that does not completely encircle a singularity. So the answer is: find the singularities of $f$, and choose your domain so that it is impossible to draw a curve in it that goes completely around any of them.

Comment: i choose one above have you checked it?

Comment: I am also looking for the largest domain

Comment: The question is, have *you* checked it? I pointed out the necessary property to check. This is your problem, not mine.